# How to use a variable as type

Tags: c#, wcf, transfer

I want to transfer BusinessObjects from one PC to another. If I think about a number of around 40 different object types to transfer the use of many contracts for the different objects would seem to be quite some overload for always the same task: "Send Object A to Computer B and save object to DB" (objects all have a persistent method).

As the Objects can have many different types, I only want to to use a generic method to:

1. serialize a BO object
2. transfer it to another PC
3. deserialize it with correct type
4. make a consistency check
5. save to db
6. is my problem.

At the moment I'm thinking about sending the type as eytra information.
Then I want to do something like:

```
BinaryFormatter aFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
aFormatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
Object.ParseTypeFromString(aObjektType) aObject = aFormatter.Deserialize(stream) as Object.ParseTypeFromString(aObjektType);
```

And afterwards just use generic methods from a base object to save object to database, to keep the transfer classes as simple as possible.

Is there a possibility to do something like this? Or am I going in a completly wrong direction and it would be easier to achieve this task with another approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the type in advance, you ***cannot*** currently be doing anything in the C# that depends on the type. `BinaryFormatter` will *already* be deserializing it with the correct object type, but you code can usually just refer to the object as.... `object`:

```
object aObject = aFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

At this point, there are various options available to you:

- use a common interface / base-class
- use `dynamic` (interesting uses of `dynamic` include calling the most appropriate overload of a method, and switching into a generic method)
- test the type explicitly with `is`, `as` or `GetType()`, for special-casing

As an example of the middle option:

```
object aObject = aFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
GenericMagic((dynamic)aObject);
OverloadMagic((dynamic)aObject);

...

void GenericMagic<T>(T obj) // possibly some constraints here too
{
    T x = ... // now we *have* the type, but as `T`;
              // of course, you still can't do many exciting
              // things unless you add constraints
}

// the correct one of these will be chosen at runtime...
void OverloadMagic(Customer cust) {...}
void OverloadMagic(User user) {...}
void OverloadMagic(Order order) {...}
```

Frankly, if I've had to deserialize (etc) something unknown I usually prefer to *stay* non-generic, just using `object`, `GetType()`, and maybe some reflection - it is still *generic*, even if it doesn't use *generics*.

Comment: Yep, what i ment is the following: Can I send an additonal string which contains the name of the type, and then use this string information as type of the object?

Comment: @Offler the object already knows its type if you are using `BinaryFormatter`. In the case of serializers like `XmlSerializer`, it will not - `Type.GetType(string)` is your best option there, but you need to store the `.AssemblyQualifiedName`, not just the `.FullName` (otherwise it won't know what assembly to look in). However, you can't make that the *variable* type; that just gives you a `Type` to use at runtime; for example `Type type = GetAndParseTheType(); var ser = new XmlSerializer(type); var obj = ser.Deserialize(stream);`

Comment: Okay, i will play around a bit to see how it works. I thought i would need something like aObjType = aObj.GetTypeFromName("ThisisMyType"); 
MethodInfo aMethod = aObjType.GetMethod("persist"); 
aMethod.Invoke(aObj, new object[0]);

Comment: @Offler the first is `Type type = Type.GetType(string)`; the second is `type.GetMethod("Persist")`, however, it would probably be easier *and* more efficient to use an interface, or `dynamic`, for that.